# Firebase doesn't store date

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have the following code:

```js
//function fires
createNewEvent = () => {
    if(Boolean(this.state.newEventName)){
        console.log(this.indexToDay) //logs right value of date
        newEvent(
            this.state.newEventName,
            this.indexToDay, 
            this.pxToTime(this.state.initial.top),
            this.pxToTime(this.state.initial.bot)
        )
    }
}


//firebase.js
export const newEvent = (name, date, top, bot) => {
    console.log(date) //logs right value of date
    const newEventRef = eventsRef.push();
    newEventRef.set({
        name,
        date,
        top,
        bot,
    })
}
```

The dates in the logs look like this: `Sat Jul 07 2018 16:40:00 GMT+0200`
But in *firebase* just the name, top, and bot appears.

Why?

Comment: you may save it as `(new Date()).getTime() `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert into the string or timestamp.

```
var d = new Date()+"";
```